# Vaadin: Reload ComboBox List while typing

Tags: combobox, vaadin

I got a ComboBox in Vaadin and want to reload (from db) the set of entries in the dropdown list while typing in the text field of the ComboBox. I always got the exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A connector should not be marked as dirty while a response is being written.
I tried to lock the session (getUI().getSession().getLockInstance().lock();), but it didn't help.

Is it possible to dynamically set/load the selection list of a ComboBox?

Cheers
Stefan

Comment: have you considered an addon like https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/suggestfield-add-on:vaadin ; or what changes to the combobox are you after, that are not already handled by the filtering options there?

Answer (score 1):

why do you want to change the content from DB as the user type? you'll get a postback and a query every key the user presses... isn't better to use the standard combo feature (which tries to autocomplete the value given what the user is typing)?

Anyway, if you really need this feature, you may extend the standard behaviour of combo extending the container behind the combo, as the data shown is taken from a container.

Comment: well, the intension is to get an instant search field (same as Google search field). While the user is typing, a list of new pattern/words is proposed.

Comment: I think your best option is to look into the container behaviour... loading data on demand, if you can't load all the possible values before.